# Не отображается AdMob, а должен ли?

Tags: android, admob

Всем доброго! 
Суть проблемы: я добавил в свое приложение баннер AdMob, описав его в .xml:

```
      <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="pub-блаблаблаблаблабл"    
        ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

Все, что нужно было сделать в манифесте и прочем, я сделал. В классе активити в OnCreate также все, вроде, сделал:

```
    adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Но после запуска приложения реклама не отображается, почему так? Может, это связано с тем, что приложение не было выложено на google play и в AdMob оно было добавлено вручную?

Кстати, а как должен выглядеть publisher id? Tак pub-1231231231231212?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Реклама будет работать и без выкладывания в GP.

2) Чтобы она работала, в

> ads:adUnitId="pub-блаблаблаблаблабл"

надо указать не идентификатор издателя, а id конкретного рекламного блока, коий надо в AdMob создать. Выглядеть он будет примерно так:

> ca-app-pub-111/111

3) Для тестирования рекламы надо указать девайс как тестовый. иначе можно на бан нарваться.

Делать это надо как-то так:

```
//get EMULATOR deviceID
String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(act.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
String deviceId = md5(android_id).toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH);

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(deviceId).build();

adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
adView.loadAd(adRequest);

public static final String md5(final String s)
{
    try
    {
        // Create MD5 Hash
        MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        digest.update(s.getBytes());
        byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

        // Create Hex String
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++)
        {
            String h = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
            while (h.length() < 2)
                h = "0" + h;
            hexString.append(h);
        }
        return hexString.toString();

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
    {
        //Logger.logStackTrace(TAG,e);
        System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: сделал все так, но проблема осталась, onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) срабатывает, код ошибки - 0

Comment: У меня этот код работает. Можно попробовать обновить все SDK, проверить ещё раз AdMob на предмет созданного там баннера, соответствия его ID тому, что прописан в XML, наличие всех разрешений и объявлений в манифесте.

Comment: В общем, все проверил и обновил. Не работает. Ошибка и все на том.Создал новый вопрос, ведь этот закрыт: должен отображаться admob. hashcode.ru/questions/390295/

Answer (score 1):

Пока что единственное предположение - это неверный adUnitId. Или же обычная задержка в показе. Когда вы создаете рекламный блок, он не сразу показывается. Точные цифры не помню, но около часа или двух должно пройти. Попробуйте тестовое приложение посмотреть, запустить и сравнить со своим. И проверьте в манифесте наличие пермишена INTERNET и активити адмоба.